# Complex forms and scripting in Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I am looking for some good tutorials on building complex forms in Access. In particular, how to get one ComboBox to populate with values based on the selection in another ComboBox.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Access Developers Handbook by Litwin, Getz and Gilbert is excellent. There are several versions, here's the amazon [link](http://www.amazon.ca/Access-2000-Developers-Handbook-Set/dp/0782123716) to the 2000 version.

[Tony Toews's online Access pages](http://www.granite.ab.ca/accsmstr.htm) are very good.

As is [The Access Web](http://mvps.org/access/): [Limit content of combo/list boxes](http://mvps.org/access/forms/frm0028.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would do something like that in an event on the ComboBox you are doing the selection on - probably the After Update event.

Then you would just update the values in the `RowSource` of the other combobox. Depending on the type, you could update the query/table, value list or field list it references.